# Recovering property with trespass

Tags: nevada

Say I land a drone on someones property.  Obviously this is trespass but how do I get the drone back? If the property owner refuses to hand it back can I demand him to?

Comment: This doesn't seem the same

Comment: The answers there appear to answer this question.  You might also explain why the tag "nevada" applies to this question?